# My computer does not show log-in window at one go. To log-in, I have to force-start the computer twice

Tags: login-screen, lock-screen

I'm using ubuntu 16.04.

This is happening for the last 1 week. Whenever I try to start my computer, it shows a blank purple-color page with no log-in window. Then I force shut down it from the power button and press the power button again. Most of the time, in the second attempt, the computer shows the log-in window. Is there a solution to this?

Please let me know if anyone knows how to solve this issue.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Log-in with older kernels didn't improve the situation.

Answer (score 0):

**Ensure your computer is running the latest BIOS available. This is important because an out-of-date BIOS can have bugs, and those bugs sometimes affect things like UEFI, non-Windows operating systems, or other components.**

★ You have a problem with grub.

- Once you logged in to ubuntu. Then try the below Command to update-grub.

```
# sudo update-grub
```

- Now, Restart your pc.
- If the problem is still, Then problem in your pc bios.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I ran the above command. But it didn't solve the problem. Any idea how can I solve my BIOS problem?

Comment: Some uncomfortable updates have created this type of problem. maybe this command help # sudo full-upgrade    . it removes unusual packages also. if this not work it means you need to check your BIOS update on your pc official site.

Comment: Even with $sudo full-upgrade, things didn't change. I think it is the problem with bios.